# Match and replace one digit with regex?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a way of prepend any single digits in a string of integers and hyphens with 0. E.g.

"-0-2-3---12-0---10-" **becomes** "-00-02-03---12-00---10-"

or

"-12-14-7-8-" **becomes** "-12-13-07-08-"

I've tried using \d{1} with a combination of dashes but it doesn't seem to capture all the correct parts. Any help would greatly appreciated. If a regex is too complex to do this do say, happen to write a traverser of some kind.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regex engine supports lookaround assertions, then this is one way to do it:

```
s/(?<!\d)(?=\d(?!\d))/0/g
```

If the regex engine doesn't support lookbehind assertions (e.g. JavaScript), then:

```
s/(^|[^\d])(?=\d(!\d))/$10/g
```

If the regex engine doesn't support lookaround assertions at all, then:

```
s/(^|[^\d])(\d)([^\d])/$10$2$3/g
```

Comment: Doesn't work in my console with sed... (I did escape the parenthesis and changed the $ to \ )

Comment: first one worked a charm in Ruby. Speed is not a issue for me so thats great, thanks

Comment: @alestanis - I believe ``sed`` needs to be in Perl mode (``-R``) for lookaround assertions to work. Without lookaround assertions, this task is impossible in a single substitution.

Comment: @acheong87 I tried the third variant just in case but it didn't work either

Comment: In `sed` the alternation operator has to be escaped as well, and `\d`s stated explicitly as `[0-9]`. This works for me: `echo -0-2-3---12-0---10- | sed 's/\(^\|[^0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([^0-9]\)/\10\2\3/g' | sed 's/\(^\|[^0-9]\)\([0-9]\)\([^0-9]\)/\10\2\3/g'` but it is pretty much the same as your solution, which is why I voted you up.

Answer (score 2):

I would use something like

```
s/-\([0-9]\)-/-0\1-/g
```

This won't work on adjacent single numbers, but if you run it twice, all numbers are caught:

```
Alejandra:~$cat tmp.txt 
-12-14-7-8-2-13-1-5-3-4-7-
Alejandra:~$sed "s/-\([0-9]\)-/-0\1-/g" tmp.txt | sed "s/-\([0-9]\)-/-0\1-/g"
-12-14-07-08-02-13-01-05-03-04-07-
```

Comment: This doesn't get adjacent single digit entries unfortunately. For the first string (-0-2-3---12-0---10-), it only matches -0-, -3- and -0-, not -2-

Comment: I just noticed that, I'm trying it with `sed` in my console

Comment: If you run it twice it will get everything though